# How to deal with accented latin characters on neovim

Tags: neovim, terminal, unicode, font

I'm trying to find out how to configure neovim in order to edit texts with accented latin characters. I usually set `ambiwidth` to `double` so Jananese symbols are displayed properly, but then neovim treats accented latin characters also as double-width. When, on the other hand, I set `ambiwidth` to `single`, the entire text gets completely disfigured, with parts of text not even displayed. Perhaps, I'm missing something?

Incidentally, I happened to notice everything is fine with vim 8.1 when `ambiwidth` is set to `single`.

I'm using the latest neovim (v0.3.1-dev) with xfce4-terminal (0.6.3) on an Ubuntu-based system (14.04).

(Solved)

I was not familiar with different sorts of terminals, but the problem resolved itself when I switched xfce4-terminal for rxvt-unicode. Now accented latin characters are displayed properly as single-width when I set `ambiwidth` to `single`.

Comment: Instead of adding "(Solved)" to the title and answering in question you can answer your questions and mark them as an answer (after 24h). This would be better option.

Answer (score 1):

At last, I guess I managed to figure out what was really at the bottom of the problem.

Older xfce4-termnal determines how to deal with ambiguous-width characters depending on the value of environment variable VTE_CJK_WIDTH (I usually set VTE_CJK_WIDTH=1), while recent xfce4-terminal has a specific setting that affects ambiguous-width characters. When I set either of these appropriately (i.e. VTE_CJK_WIDTH to 0 or 'ambiguous-width characters' to 'narrow') and also set `ambiwidth` to `single` with neovim, then everything goes well and neovim treats accented latin characters as single-width.

As far as I understand, rxvt-unicode cannot properly deal with ambiguous-width characters and always treats these characters as single-width. So this may not be a proper solution to the problem.